# XNA value of Apply3D positions

Tags: xna

I'm currently working on 3d positional audio in my 3d XNA game (using SoundEffectInstance), however I'm having troubles finding the correct values of the position of the emitter and listers.

I started out setting the position of my listener to the camera position(it's a first person game), and the position of the various emitters to the position of the object that was emitting the sound. Doing this muted the sound completely, compared to before I used the Apply3D method.

I did some experimenting with the values, and figured after I made the values of the positions much much smaller, I started hearing the sound. My map size has values from 0 to 5000 in the x/z plane (only moving between 0 and ~500 on y axis), so the distance between the listener and emitter will generally be high (when comparing to the values I needed to hear anything at all which was between 0 and 1).

Is there any way to control what "close" and "far away" is for the soundEffectInstance? Or am I supposed to normalize the distance values? I read trough several guides on 3D sound, but I have not seen anything related to normalizing or control of the distance values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing, I found that simply dividing the position values with a factor (arround 500 seems right for me) provides a good result. I dont know if this is the way It's supposed to be done, but it seems to be working fine.